# SQL Group by return one row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

Using SQL Server 2014.  I seem to me having a moment and can't get my head around it.

This is my table:

```
Field1   Field2  Field3
123      1        I
123      2        I
123      3        U
123      4        I
123      5        I
123      6        U
```

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT        Field1, COUNT(Field2) AS CR_P
FROM            MyTable
GROUP BY Field1, Field3
HAVING        (Field3 <> N'D')
```

However, I get the below:

```
Field1   CR_P  
123      4        
123      2
```

But I really want:

```
Field1   CR_P  
123      6
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of HAVING use a WHERE clause and remove Field3 from GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the correct query for you.

```
SELECT        Field1, COUNT(Field2) AS CR_P
FROM          MyTable
GROUP         BY Field1
WHERE         (Field3 <> N'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `COUNT()` function as shown below:

```
create table TblData(Field1 int,
Field2 int,
Field3 char(1))

insert into TblData values
(123, 1, 'I'),
(123, 2, 'I'),
(123, 3, 'U'),
(123, 4, 'I'),
(123, 5, 'I'),
(123, 6, 'U')

Select distinct Field1, 
Count(Field2) OVER (Partition By Field1) as CR_P
FROM TblData
--where Field3 <> 'U'
```

[**Live Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c39b68aae2878be2eac03427bc49451a)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT Field1, COUNT(Field2) AS CR_P
FROM  MyTable
WHERE Field3 <> N'D'
GROUP BY Field1;
```